# Call UIApplication sharedApplication openURL from background

Tags: ios, background, uiapplication

I need return to app after call. Or i need make phone call from background.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://%@",phoneNumber];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
}
```

But i have not idea how to do this.

Comment: You can  not redirect to the app while calling another app by using [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];

Comment: Ok. But i need return after call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to make a phone call in the background, but I haven't figured it out yet. However, to answer your question, you could use @"telprompt://%@" instead of @"tel://%@". This will pop up a little alert with the option to cancel or call, and upon ending the phone call the user will be returned to the app.